# Objective-C ID3 framework?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, cocoa, id3-tag

I am trying to add/replace album art of MP3 files. Is there an Objective-C framework that will allow me to do this? If not, what the best way to do this? I don't mind using C or C++ but it's better if it's in Objective-C. Thanks!

Update: I found an audio framework called SFBAudioEngine which can edit metadata of several audio formats but when I compile the sample project in it, I get 2094 errors.

Comment: I have a question: in what way is this related to Xcode?

Comment: @eddy- ok?
@radek: check the update, i am compiling using xcode and maybe i am missing some sort of setting, thats why its related.

Comment: @use635064: It's not. Your question is about a framework, not Xcode. The litmus test is “would my question be any different if I were using vi and make”, and the answer for this question is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a strict superset of C itself, I would suggest compiling a library that handles ID3 tags ([id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) or [libid3tag](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) come to mind) and use their functions directly or build a class around what they provide. Good luck!